# flask templates works in local env but return error 404 under nginx

Tags: python, templates, nginx, flask, http-status-code-404

I 've read answer [https://stackoverflow.com/a/20895594/305883] but did not help for me.

I have a flask app that **can serve a template in localhost** or debug at endpoint `/path/<int:id>/`, but in production with **nginx** it will **fail** with **error 404**.

Flask project has default structure:

```
app.py
index.html
/templates/mytemplate.html
/static/..
```

`mytemplate.html` will load resources from `/static/` folder, with jinja syntax.

**EDITED**

**Goal:** I want the application to serve:

- root `/` will serve index.html
- `/path/` will open 'myTemplate.html' and populate it with variables
  (jinja); if possible I want static assets included in template (e.g
  js, css, images) to be served by nginx;
- `/api/` will serve api rest.

In my local environment I am using flask server, not ningx, and three end-points are working as expected.

In production, I use flask and ningx.
Root and /api/ edges work; /path/ , used for templating in flask, does not and return **error 404**.

For setting up nginx I followed the steps in this tutorial:
[https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04]

The template in flask is served by:

```
@application.route('/path/<int:id>/')
def graph_template(id):
    meta = {'og:image':'/url/image.jpg'}
    try:
        key = decode(id)[0]
    except:
        # todo replace with error 400
        return jsonify({'error':'Something got wrong. ID not found'})
    return render_template('mytemplate.html', meta=meta, id = id)
```

I am having difficulties in debugging and find the problem, making `/path/` display the template.

**nginx configuration**

```
server {
    listen 80;

    #  is this block to serve index on root only ?
    #  or will search for index files also in routes /path/ in ningx and/or flask? 
       root /var/www/mySite;
        index index.html index.htm;

        location /api {
    #       try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
            include uwsgi_params;
            uwsgi_pass unix:/var/www/mySite/myApp.sock;

    #        auth_basic "API Login";
    #        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/pw_file;
    #        allow 127.0.0.1;
    #       allow XX.XX.XXX.XXX;
    #        deny all;
        }

    location /static {
    alias /var/www/mySite/static;
    }

}
```

I tried the following:

Included a proxy_pass:

```
location / {
   proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080; 
}
```

result: cause **error 502**

Tried by changing port to :80

```
location / {
   proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:80; 
}
```

result: **error 404**

Tried with uwsgi_pass socket at /path/ endpoint

```
location /path/ {
   include uwsgi_params;
   uwsgi_pass unix:/var/www/mySite/myApp.sock; 
}
```

Result: **This route does not exist http://example.com/path/** 
Which I don't understand because flask should serve the template here - at least not a misconfiguration error 502.

Answer at: [[Python Flask server crashing on GET request to specific endpoint:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20790833/python-flask-server-crashing-on-get-request-to-specific-endpoint]) shown two sockets for each endpoint - do I need to use such setup?
I m trying to document myself on what a socket is and using nginx documentation but sorry I m not that competent in it and I m moving a bit in darkness.

Could you help in debugging the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YAII! I was able to find the answer myself:

adding this block in nginx worked out for **serving templates from flask with nginx**:

```
location /path/ {
   include uwsgi_params;
   uwsgi_pass unix:/var/www/mySite/myApp.sock; 
}
```

where `/path/` is the endpoint of the template.

I was receiving the message above because flask was actually handling the 404 error, due to I wrote my decorator to hit `/path/<int:id>` and handling 404 requests with:

```
@application.errorhandler(404)
def page_not_found(error):
    return 'This route does not exist {}'.format(request.url), 404
```

However, I will be very grateful if someone could add some comments explaining how the routing between flask and nginx actually works, and a distinction between using a `uwsgi_pass` and `proxy_pass` (which I found in different tutorials), and the use of sockets (tutorial I followed).

As example, in this question [[Python Flask server crashing on GET request to specific endpoint:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20790833/python-flask-server-crashing-on-get-request-to-specific-endpoint]) the user use two sockets for each endpoint, and for me as beginner I thought it may have been the issue and it is not.

- With this configuration, I understood flask will handle the .html template: does it handle also the resource in the template (js, css) or are they served by nginx (please see configuration above, all assets are in /static/ folder)
- Would there be a better configuration to exploit ningx capabilities in serving flask templates ?

Comments most appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I assume your *local env* works without `nginx`, right? So, lets have a look:

> In local environment, hitting `/path/` (with no id) will return an error of `url not found`, which is ok. Instead in prod environment, nginx will search for `/path/index.html` - although I have not mentioned in flask decorator.

Have a look at line three of your `nginx` config. In there, you specified that `nginx` should look for `index.html`.

> In local env, if I hit `/path/id/` it works ok. In production env, it returns error 404, `no such file or directory`.

I assume, this is because you don't pass any traffic to your `flask app`. You need something along the lines of:

```
location / {
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080; #Change to match your environment
}
```

You're missing these (if not, please show your whole `nginx` config), so `nginx` will search for static files on your storage. However, these requests can't be served by static files, but instead your `backend` (aka your `flask app`) has to render and create these dynamically. For this to work, you have to send the traffic there.

> I have not found an error due to failing with resources from `/static/` folder (e.g. in permission); it looks like flask cannot load or be allowed to serve the templates.
>
> Template file can be loaded by the browser at `/mysite/templates/mytemplate.html` Static folder permission is set on 403, but `/static/js/file.js` will be read.

Sorry, I don't get this. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Hi @gf_ in _local env_ is ok. In my ningx configuration I serve index.html only in root, see update. About passing traffic to flask: I tried to add and returns now `502 error`; but on nginx error.log there no additional explanations. Should match port 80 listened by the server? Flask is serving the API endpoint correctly, not template - possible to make flask complete the jinja block and let nginx to serve the final html file?

Comment: Don't know what you mean by "Should match port 80 listened by the server". Please edit your question ahd _clearly_ state, which requests work, and which doesn't. Besides this, please describe your _local env_: What are the differences between this and _production_? Regarding your `nginx` config: You're passing traffic to a socket: Does this socket exist? Is it pointing to your `flask app`? If so, you've to alter my given example accordingly: Change the `proxy_pass` directive to your `uwsgi_pass` one..and note my comment reading "Change to match your environment".